# Chromedriver to click a button on web page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

With Python and chromedriver, I want to click a little triangle on the webpage (company internal) which leads to its "Next Page".

I gave long time.sleep() to the page loading, and tried either below but they still don't work:

```
chromedriver = "C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

time.sleep(5)

verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

driver.get("the_website")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(50)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title=\'Next_page'\]").click()
# also: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tabs"]/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()
```

The error says:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[title="Next_page"]"}
```

What's the right way to click it? Thank you.

*Info:*

Here are the copies in different forms, by using Chrome browser and inspected the element:

Outer:

```
<a style="background: url('./img/next.png') center center no-repeat;" title="Next_page" href="#1" onclick="click"></a>
```

Selector:

```
tabs > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="tabs"]/div/ul/li[3]/a
```

Element:

```
<a style="background: url('./img/next.png') center center no-repeat;" title="Next_page" href="#1" onclick="click"></a>
```

Comment: Share the error you faced with the code you tried. Have you tried WebDriverWait?

Comment: @Kamal, thank you for the comment. It's a company internal page so excuse me not able to post the link. I gave long time.sleep() to it but still count not find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the xpath: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[@title='Next_page']")`

And please check if the element is in iframe, if yes, then switch to the iframe and then click on the button, to switch to iframe you can use: `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))` and then click on the element using the given xpath and if you want to switch back to the default content, you can use `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: @Sameer_Arora, thank you! switching it to the iframe is the key. however, the click, in my case, needs Ibaboiii's line to do the job. :)

Comment: Happy to help you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title = "Next_page"]").click()
```

Comment: thank you for the input! your line does the job. however it needs to be switched to the iframe before the click.